# Insert array of dictionary’s into MySQL Database using node

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am sending an array of dictionary objects to my server to insert into a database using node and MySQL.

If I were inserting just one row I would use the following:

var user = event.user

And sql:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (user_id, username, user_email) VALUES (user.userId, user.username, user.userEmail)
```

However for the case that an array of users is being sent to the server I’m not sure how to iterate through the user array and populate the values section of the sql statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all dependent on what library you are using to interface with MySQL, but here is an example using [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql):

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'mydb',
  debug: false,
});

connection.connect();

console.log("Connected to Mysql");

var records = [
  [1, 'foo', 'bar'],
  [2, 'biz', 'baz'],
  [3, 'fiz', 'biz']
];

var sql = "INSERT INTO employee (employee_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES ?";

var query = connection.query(sql, [records], function(err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});

connection.end();
```